# Internet Explorer 11 cannot download any files

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, download

at this point, I am working on a pc, where you cannot download any files. If you klick a download link, a new Tab opens for ca. 0.1 sec and closes, nothing more is happening.

- Currently what i've done:
- I have uninstalled IE11 in `optionalfeatures`
- Then I deleted everything I could find in AppData about the IE
- Set the Securty-Options to default (Downloads are enabled)

On another user it is working. I really dont know anymore. Maybe you have some tipps.

Edit: Chrome and Firefox are working
Edit²: Recreating the user did not affect anything, sadly

Comment: For completeness in debugging: Do you have another browser on the system (e.g, Firefox or Chrome), and if so, can the user having problems with IE download using that other browser?

Comment: Oh, Im sorry, i just edited it

Comment: Have you disabled all add-ons, deleted cache data/cookies/history/etc.? You may need to resort to backing up user files and settings, deleting the user from the computer, and re-creating. Is this a standalone computer, or a domain-connected computer, and, if the latter, have you checked to make sure there are no domain policies that may be interfering?

Comment: This Computer is connected to a domain. I deleted all the history and stuff. What do you think will happen if I delete the user but not its data. I cannot delete the data

Comment: As I understand it, you cannot delete the user's profile without deleting the data; in my environment, we have (in most cases) the user's documents stored on a NAS, rather than the local computer, and bar access to the local drives by policy, so we can delete user profiles with impunity in most cases. Where certain users have access to the local drives, we have to back up Documents, Downloads, Favorites, etc., before doing anything to the profile - but if we feel we have to resort to that, we will. It's amazing how many sins are expiated by a profile delete/re-create.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: You may need to resort to a professional troubleshooting organization who can work with you "live", possibly via remote control. It's likely that your problem is beyond what can reasonably be expected to be solved from StackExchange.

Comment: Thats not an option

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps we can try to identify, troubleshoot or resolve the problem.

Way1: It may be because the "Temporary Internet Files" folder is corrupted. Simply emptying it does not fix this issue, it needs to be "moved" from our computer(we can find "Temporary Internet Files" by the following screenshot). It does not reboot the computer, but it does log off the user.

Way2: I find when the temporary IE files have reached capacity of the settings set for IE. Maybe we can not download and pages may not open either try deleting your temp files and  history.

Click the gear top right and delete browsing.

Click the internet options.

In the homepage clear that and type in about blank then at the bottom apply do not use the other's like "Use Current" or "Use default".

On the general Tab>tick to delete browsing history on exit,  if you do not mind deleting them manually do not change that.

Next to that is Settings> Disk Space to use maybe set at 250 megs I have mine at 330 megs to cover some of the downloads as they maybe big(we can set it as several hundreds). If you have plenty of  HDD space add more if you download big files then empty your cache.
[image]

The other **three ways** we can refer in this article:
[Cannot download a file from the Internet](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-download-file-internet)